# "Il me l'a promis" ou "Il m'en a promis" ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi est-ce qu'on emploie le pronom "le" dans cette phrase :

> Il viendra pour les 80 ans de sa grand-mère ; il me **l**’a promis.

Est-il possible d'utiliser "en" au lieu de "le" selon cette logique :

> Il m'a promis *de venir*. --> Il m'*en* a promis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I**
Non, il n'y a aucune possibilité de cela; le point à garder en tête pour savoir où utiliser « le » et  « en » est que « le » est utilisé pour un COD et « en » lorsque la préposition « de » est utilisé dans la forme verbale suivie d'un objet.

> Il m'a promis ce chapeau. Il me l'a promis.
> Il m'a promis de la confiture de rose pour Noël. Il m'en a promis.

Voilà un cas plus compliqué où « de » n'est pas la préposition à laquelle on s'attend *naturellement* (suggéré par [user XouDo](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33173/il-me-la-promis-ou-il-men-a-promis/33178?noredirect=1#comment93310_33178)).

> On m'a promis un tour de manège. On m'en a promis un.

Dans ce dernier cas la syntaxe se justifie selon la définition suivante du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en).

> > **I.** [L'antécédent est explicite et de nature nom.]
> > **A.** [L'antécédent est un subst., un adv. ou un pron.]
> > **2.** [L'antécédent est repris avec une détermination propre qui ne figure pas dans l'antécédent; en corresp. à l'art. indéf.]
> > **a)** [Le déterm. est un quantificateur qui précise une partie par rapport au tout que l'antécédent est supposé représenter]
> > **− [un numéral à valeur précise]**
> > ♦ En voilà deux, tout de même, deux curés que je vois mourir ici (Bernanos, Crime,1935, p. 729).
> > ♦ Sur ces treize millions, il y en a dix que j'ai perdu dans le coup des Sonchelles (Druon, Gdes fam.,t. 2, 1948, p. 200)
> > ♦ Il y a un long silence, pendant lequel l'Archevêque compulse des papiers qui lui ont été passés par le Grand Vicaire. Il finit par en signer un. Il en donne d'autres au Lieutenant civil. Montherlant, Port-Royal,1954, p. 1023.
>
> (Rem. GÉNÉRALITÉS **4.** À l'intérieur de la prop. où il est placé, en remplit auprès des termes de cette prop. toutes les fonctions assumées par de, soit dans ses emplois de prép., soit dans ses emplois d'art. indéf. ou partitif.)

**II**
Évidemment, cela n'est pas seulement vrai pour le verbe « promettre » ; tous les verbes sont sujets à ce principe.

> Il se sert de petit bois pour allumer le feu. Il s'en sert.
> Il se sert une bière bien fraiche. Il se la sert.
> Ils mangent de la confiture de rhubarbe. Ils en mangent. 
> Elle a mangé toute la confiture de rhubarbe. Elle **l'** a toute mangée.

Comment: vous m'en direz tant …

Comment: @5915961T Je suis peut être un peu porté à trop multiplier les exemples…

Comment: On pourrais ajouter ce cas là aussi : *On m'a promis un tour de manège. On m'en a promis un.*

Comment: @XouDo En effet, voilà un cas qui montre de nouvelles difficultés parmi celles que réserve ce pronom.